# Create a new image using REST API by placing the content in the request body

Tags: docker

I am following the "Create an image" REST API for docker mentioned at https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.21/#create-an-image .

I want to create an image by placing the content in the request body. The explanation on the link does not specify exactly how the request and request body should look like in this scenario.

Does anyone know how should I construct the request URL and body for this REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tracing the behavior of the `docker import` command, it is apparent that the `/images/create` endpoint expects data in the form of a tar archive containing the files to populate the image.  I after creating a simple archive containing a single file:

```
tar -c -f image.tar README
```

I was able to upload the image like this:

```
curl http://localhost:5555/images/create'?fromSrc=-&repo=larstest&tag=latest' \
  -T image.tar -X POST
```

The response from `docker` was:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2015 15:10:10 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"status":"2df6c21713e01af0118bbe2810307c2111e1d0168463affffe5c517d4debb7db"}
```

You can trace the behavior of the `docker` client by setting up a logging proxy between the client and the server.  I did this:

```
socat -v tcp-listen:5555,fork,reuseaddr unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And then ran `docker` like this:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:5555 docker import - larstest < image.tar
```